# Match function parameters from an associative array and function call in PHP

Tags: php, function, reflection

I have an associative array in the following form:

```
$params = array(
    'paramName_4'=>'param_4', 
    'paramName_2'=>'param_2',
    // ...,
    'paramName_6'=>'param_6',
);
```

and I also have a function `myFunction` defined as:

```
public function myFunction($paramName_1, $paramName_2, $paramName_3, ....);
```

Does a a "parsing" function exist in PHP so that I can call function `myFunction` by matching the parameters (even if they are not sorted wrt the `myFunction`'s parameter sequence)? In other words, can I do

```
my_magic(__NAMESPACE__.'\\myFunction', $params);
```

Does this "magic" function does exist? If not, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php). Here's how:

```
// The input is the array of arguments and the function name
$arguments = array(....);
$functionName = __NAMESPACE__.'\\myFunction';

$reflector = new \ReflectionFunction($functioName);
$params = $reflector->getParameters();
$values = array();

foreach ($params as $param) {
    $name = $param->getName();
    $isArgumentGiven = array_key_exists($name, $arguments);
    if (!$isArgumentGiven && !$param->isDefaultValueAvailable() {
        die ("Parameter $name is mandatory but was not provided");
    }

    $values[$param->getPosition()] =
        $isArgumentGiven ? $arguments[$name] : $param->getDefaultValue();
}

// You can now call the function:
call_user_func($functionName, $values);
```

Comment: Is it efficient or it is preferable to avoid this kind of function calls?

Comment: @JeanValjean: It is highly inefficient, so don't do it in a loop. But it can be a great convenience if used sparingly. This code as adapted from one of my own functions, so I certainly find it useful.

Comment: +1, but I think I'd just sort the params into the correct order; Reflection seems like overkill.

Comment: @Jon I should provide a compiled version of the class in order to improve the performance, but for such a rare call is too much work :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Reflection as per @Jon's example, but if the problem is just that the params aren't in the right order, why not just use `ksort()` or `uksort()` to put them in the right order.

Then you can use `call_user_func_array()`. Problem solved.

```
$params = array(....);

uksort($params, function($a,$b) {
    //sort the params into the known order....
    $sortOrder = array('param1','param2','param3','param4');
    return (array_search($a, $sortOrder) > array_search($b, $sortOrder)) ? -1 : 1;
});

//now that $params is in the right order we can do this....
$retVal = call_user_func_array($func, $params);
```

I've hard-coded the param order here, because it's the most efficient way. If you are calling a function where you don't know the correct param order in advance, then yes, you'll need to use reflection. But I would think that's fairly unlikely (passing an unknown params list into an unknown function sounds like a goldmine for hackers)

Comment: Because this would only work if the parameters had names that sorted in the same order as they appear in the function signature. No real function has parameters named `param1`, `param2`.

Comment: @Jon - that's why you'd probably use `uksort()`. Just write a small sorting function that puts the parameters into the order you expect; it can be any order you like.

Comment: But you don't know what the correct order is, or you don't want to hardcode it. That's why you have to reflect.

Comment: well yes... if you don't know what the order is, then yes, you'll have to use reflection. But really? Taking a list of params, presumably direct from user input (`$_POST`?), and passing them into a function that we don't know in advance?? That sounds like a hackers dream.

Comment: @SDC My question was for internal use, not for matching the params in an HTTP request! I believe that what I asked is what many web application frameworks do (e.g. Symfony for the route-to-controller matching)

Comment: @JeanValjean - fair enough. My objective here was to avoid using Reflection, mainly due to the fact that it's wildly inefficient. My solution is aimed at a situation where you have a known method that you're going to call, and only the order of the input is unknown. That's how I read the question, and I think my solution is more pragmatic in that case. But if you want a generic solution where the methodname is also a variable, then yes, Jon's answer is better, albeit slower.

Comment: @SDC I know that and I appreciate your effort! +1. Notwithstanding that, I believe that your solution is a little bit tortuous to be applied on many functions and not so flexible (suppose that I change the order in a function params). :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library which does the argument resolving for a given function/method: [ArgumentsResolver](https://github.com/rybakit/arguments-resolver).